# R CMD check stops at "checking Rd cross-references"

Tags: r

I am using `devtools::check(document=FALSE,args=c('--no-multiarch'))` to perform the checks for my package.

When the above command performs `R --vanilla CMD check "C:\sometmpfolder/mypackage.tar.gz" --timings --no-multiarch`,
it stops at

```
* checking Rd cross-references ...
```

i.e., this is the last line in `mypackage.Rcheck/00check.log`. There is no error message - the check seems to freeze.

I use `roxygen2` to create my documentation. The cross references that I use are of the form `\link{somefunction}` and `\link[somepkg]{somefunction}`.

I am running R 3.1.2 on a Win 7 machine.
But I think that I have seen a similar behaviour with earlier versions of R and without `roxygen2` as well.

Do you guys know why the check stops at the cross-references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that an incorrect statement of the form

```
\link[somepkg]{somefunction}
```

was the problem. In my case I used the incorrect command `\link[reshape]{melt}` although it should be `\link[reshape2]{melt}`.
This caused the `Rd` cross-reference check to take forever (actually, it finished after nearly one hour). After correcting to `\link[reshape2]{melt}` the `Rd` cross-reference check only took a minute or so.